# How can I dynamically fill a column in Google Sheets that is producing the smallest date value from a row?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

In this [Test Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ULsFusC9vSRIMhok985SDmVXwwJrA4EblMRe8dwiWfQ/edit?usp=sharing) I have several columns that may or may not contain dates. I have used a `=small(A2:E2, 1)` to provide me with the smallest date for a row... but I want to dynamically fill in the data down the column for every row that has values in it.

The data in my real-world example is being pulled in by a query and could easily update and include additional rows of data. I tried using Arrayformula and the following formula `=Arrayformula(small(A2:E, 1))` but as expected small is looking though that whole array of columns and rows rather than just a single row. I need to know if there is a simple way to dynamically replicate the individual row down through any row that contains data? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A2:F),
 "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, 
 "min(Col"&ROW(A2:A)-ROW(A2)+1&")")&"")),
 "select Col2"))
```

[image]

Comment: That worked! Can you explain what that formula is doing?

Comment: sure, idea is to transpose A2:F in order to use the ability of QUERY to find min value per column. then it's just transposed back to the original state and only Col2 is selected (Col1 contains labels) via 2nd query. TEXTJOIN just creates a string: min(Col1),min(Col2),min(Col3), etc. and the part `-ROW(A2)+1` accounts for the fact that table starts from row 2 onwards eg A2:F

Comment: That is fabulous. What a great solution. It just opened up a whole new world for me. haha.